# How do you skip subDags in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I'm trying to understand whether Airflow supports skipping subDags in a DAG.

Let's say my DAG looks like this: task1(FileSensor) -> task2(subDag-1) -> task3(subDag-2) -> task4(subDag-3)

Suppose I have a list of subDags I want to run, such as `['1','3']`, meaning that I want to run task1, then task2, then task4, skipping task3. (The list of subDags to be run will be provided through configuration while triggering the DAG.)

I have looked into skipping tasks using `PythonOperator`, but I don't want to use taks2, task3, and task4 with `PythonOperator`. I also want to mark SubDAG as 'skipped' in Airflow UI.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

EDIT: Since SubDags are depreciated in favor of `TaskGroups`, I used `TaskGroups` and added a PythonOperator in case I wanted to skip TaskGroup.
It worked for me!

Comment: What version of Airflow are you running? SubDags are deprecated. You should try to avoid them.

Comment: @Elad I am using Airflow v2.0.0. It is the requirement of my DAG to use subDags, that's why I can't avoid using them in my case.

Comment: Subdags will be deprecated https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/12292 You should use Tasks Groups https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#taskgroup

Answer (score 0):

An option can be to use a **branch operator** and move the skipping (aka branching aka conditionals) logic to the branch operator.

Checkout the following links -

- Airflow Documentation -
  https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html?highlight=branch#branching
- Example - https://www.cloudwalker.io/2019/07/29/airflow-branch-joins/